# ActionBuilder is returning requestBody as null

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm developing a scala Web application with play framework, the first time i used filter in order to validate the request but i had no result then i tried to use action builder i had to override 2 methods  here is my ActionBuilder Object

```
object MyJsonAction extends ActionBuilder[Request, Response] with Results {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
    println (request.body)// returning null everytime why ?
       block(request)
  }

  override def parser = { // what does this method do, i think the problem started from here :/ ?
    null;

  }

  override protected def executionContext = {

    null;
  }
}
```

Well, there are no much resource with play framework just simple examples and there is no example briefly explain what those methods are doing, **they tell that you can get request body without telling you how !** everything is ambiguous ! im stuck with it since 3 days a go, and i have no idea what should i do now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ActionBuilder` is an object that build an `Action`. An `Action` combines a `BodyParser[T]`, which reads the request body and constructs a `T`, with a function `Request[T] => Future[Result]` to process the `T`.

The default `ActionBuilder` does this in a very simple way. It chains together the `BodyParser`'s result and feeds it to the function. If you make a custom `ActionBuilder` then you can override this process, perhaps by injecting your own logic before or after the function call.

If you're making your own `ActionBuilder` I'd suggest starting with something like the following as a template:

```
@Singleton
class MyJsonAction @Inject() (
  bodyParsers: PlayBodyParsers,
  ec: ExecutionContext) extends ActionBuilder[Request, JsValue] {

  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
    println(request.body) // DO SOMETHING HERE
    block(request)
  }
  override def parser = bodyParsers.json
  override protected def executionContext = ec
}
```

Then you can use it in your controllers like this:

```
class MyController @Inject() (myJsonAction: MyJsonAction) {
  def index = myJsonAction { req: Request[JsValue] => ??? }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The important piece is the `parser: BodyParser[A]` it takes the incoming bytes and convert them into a type `A`.

For instance `BodyParser[JsValue]` will produce a body of type `JsValue`. It is used to read Json.

If you are trying to validate an object, maybe an action builder is not the right place to start. You may focus more on the [BodyParsers](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaBodyParsers#Body-parsers) and the [json validation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonHttp#Creating-a-new-entity-instance-in-JSON)

Comment: can you tell me why ? action builder is not good place to validate json request ?

Comment: In my opinion the body parser is already responsible for this. But as @rich-dougherty suggested, you can also do it in the action builder. It's not "a bad place" it depends on how you structure your application and it's more important to keep things coherent and simple for you